# Protobuf .net: When deserializing a message that contains pre-initialized repeated fields, the default fields are not cleared

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message with a repeated field like this:

```protobuf
message Foo {
  repeated int32 ints = 1;
}
```

I implemented `OnConstruction` in the generated partial class like this:

```cs
partial class Foo {

  partial void OnConstruction() {
    Ints.Add(42);
    Ints.Add(43);
  }
}
```

This works, when creating a new `Foo` the `Ints` is correctly initialized.

However, when I serialize this message to JSON or to binary, and I deserialize this again, the values are *appended* to the list, so that `Ints` then contains `42, 43, 42, 43`.

How can I avoid `OnConstruction` being called when deserializing - or avoid merging the message altogether?